# Implementing a HPRIM Net encryption / decryption algorithm

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to implement a HPRIM Net end-to-end encrypted messaging system for the medical sector.

From what I read, `Version 1 of HPRIM Net requires a X509 digital certificate to secure messages. This security is implemented with S/MIME protocol that allows messages signature and encryption.`

To be honest, I don't understand what that means. Granted that I do have the .pem digital certificate in question, *how would one implement (preferably in Python) an encoding/decoding algorithm based on it and the sender/recipient certificate signature file?*

Again, sorry if my question seems vague. Any clue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read up on CMS / PKCS#7, it's [an RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652). Then find a library implementing it because it's not something you should try implement yourself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not (yet) related to programming.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll look into that direction and will update my post when I know more about it!